# Corona SDK physics game not working properly on Android device

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

I'm new to Corona and game development. I am making a simple game with physics to move objects with touch. Here is my code

```
local physics = require"physics";
local gameUI = require("gameUI")

physics.setDrawMode( "normal" )
physics.setScale( 40)
physics.setPositionIterations( 60 )

physics.start();

local _H=display.contentHeight;
local _W=display.contentWidth;

local crat1=display.newImageRect("crate1.png",40,40)
crat1.x=20;crat1.y=200;
physics.addBody(crat1,"dynamic",{density=-1000,bounce=0.1,friction=100});

local function dragBody_call(event)
--Calling drawBody() From gameUI
gameUI.dragBody(event);

end    

crat1:addEventListener( "touch", dragBody_call) -- make object draggable
```

In the simulator, movement and touch events are working perfectly and it also runs on Android device. Physics works perfectly and I can also move objects with Touch but it's very laggy and very hard to move a objects. And sometime it does not move. It's not as smooth as simulator. How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't believe your handset is slower than the emulator - usually, it's the other way around :).  But it sounds like your handset needs more RAM or a faster cpu

Comment: i have galaxy s3... :) i dont think it's not sufficient for simple physics game problem is something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the the problem is your

```
physics.setPositionIterations( 60 )
```

According to the docs

> The default value is 8, which means that the engine will iterate
>   through eight position approximations per frame for each object.
>   Increasing this number will cause fewer momentary inaccuracies
>   (overlapping objects. etc.) **but will increase computational overhead**.
>   The default value should be good for most general cases.

See here http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setPositionIterations.html

Remove that line or if you REALLY need performance, increase it by a smaller value. Say to 12 or 16.